# KeyError: "Invalid split train[:80%]. Available splits are: ['train']" in TensorFlow official tutorial

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

At [Link:](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning)https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning

`(raw_train, raw_validation, raw_test), metadata = tfds.load(
    'cats_vs_dogs',
    split=['train[:80%]', 'train[80%:90%]', 'train[90%:]'],
    with_info=True,
    as_supervised=True,
)`

why there is an error

`KeyError: "Invalid split train[:80%]. Available splits are: ['train']"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this code
We can split it in TF 2 as:

```
(raw_train, raw_validation, raw_test), metadata = tfds.load(
'cats_vs_dogs',
split=[
   tfds.Split.TRAIN.subsplit(tfds.percent[:80]),
   tfds.Split.TRAIN.subsplit(tfds.percent[80:90]),
   tfds.Split.TRAIN.subsplit(tfds.percent[90:])
],
with_info=True,
as_supervised=True,
)
```

Comment: If this is only way tensorflow should update their docs